# can't get JwPlayer to play from Rackspace CDN

Tags: jwplayer, rackspace-cloud

## *UPDATE*

- It would appear the "Direct/Download URL" from Rackspace WORKS!
- But, the "Stream URL", which worked with FloPlayer, Does NOT WORK with jwPlayer!?

---

I can get the images to load, I can get the urls to come from the post ajax just fine. I cant get everything working except the video. No clue what's wrong honestly.

### HEAD

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jdPlugs.js"></script> // personal lib (jQuery extendor)

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="";</script>
```

### JS (FULL)

```
var rackCDN = "http:// rackspace cloud link .com";

(function($) {
    if (!$.jwplayer) {
        $.extend({
            jwplayer: function(elm, command, args) {
                if ($.jwplayer.methods[arguments[0]]) return $.jwplayer.methods[arguments[0]].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                if (typeof elm == "string") return jwplayer(elm);
                return jwplayer(elm.prop("id"));
            }
        });
        $.jwplayer.methods = {
            load: function() { return jwplayer().load([arguments[0]]); },
            play: function() { return jwplayer().play(); },
            pause: function() { return jwplayer().pause(); }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

function liClick() {
    var key = $(this).data("key"),
        opts = {
            file: rackCDN+key,
            image: rackCDN+key
        };
    console.log(opts);
    $.jwplayer("load", opts);
}

$(function() {
    $.jwplayer("testPlayer01").setup({
        file: "http:// rackspace cloud link .com/2013/03/20130303-message-service-hd.mp4",
        image: "http:// rackspace cloud link .com/video-stills/large/542.jpg",
        provider: "<?php echo(base_url('js/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf')); ?>",
        height: "480",
        width: "600"
    });

    $("li a").on("click", liClick);

    $("button").on("click", function(e) {
        $.jwplayer($.trim($(this).text()));
    });

    $("h3").css({ cursor: "pointer" }).on("click", function(e) {
        $.getJSON($.myURL("controllers/getList.php"), function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if ($.objLength(data) > 0) {
                $("ul").empty();
                for (x in data) {
                    $("<li />").append($("<a />", { "data-key": data[x].name, href: "javascript:void(0)", text: data[x].name })).appendTo($("ul"));
                }
                $("li a").on("click", liClick).first().click();
            }
        });
    })
})
```

### JS (Focal point, i think)

```
$.jwplayer("testPlayer01").setup({
    file: "http:// a working link .mp4",
    image: "http:// a working link .jpg",

    // link tested, file does reside here
    provider: "<?php echo(base_url('js/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf')); ?>", 
    height: "480",
    width: "600"
});
```

And yes I have my header includes and no i'm not getting any console errors other than the jwerror, code 4.

```
MediaError
    code: 4
    __proto__: MediaError
    MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1
    MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3
    MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED: 5
    MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2
    MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4
```

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this? I know that the new provider has been causing issues though that Akamai put out, we have been trying to work with them on the issues, but it has taken some time.

Comment: @EthanLongTail I dont. Just a local setup at moment and I can't find a good way to jsfiddle it with key and all. I will edit to show more code tho, maybe i'm setting something up wrong ...

Comment: The code looks totally OK to me. Can you email us something that we can test locally? - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: @EthanLongTail OK, I submitted code as suggested and got an email back from R**** saying it was outside ya'lls scope of help. Any other suggestions here?

Comment: @EthanLongTail Also, update to question, it appears the Download link (not meant for streaming) is working with jwplayer, but the stream link (we previously used in floplayer) does not work!?

Comment: I really would need to see something in order to debug this properly at this point.